# Soft break / Alternative for <wbr> for email-clients

Tags: html, html-email

I want to email a html-email with PHP containing a link like:

https://www.example.com/this/is/a/very/long/link/which/might/be/toooooooooooooooolooooooooooooooooooong/

The problem is that the long link might destroy the layout of the email. I don't want to hide the link behind a button or something like this.

So the idea was just to add `<wbr>` like:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/this/is/a/very/long/link/which/might/be/toooooooooooooooolooooooooooooooooooong/">
https://www.example.com/<wbr>this/<wbr>is/<wbr>a/<wbr>very/<wbr>long/<wbr>link/<wbr>which/<wbr>might/<wbr>be/<wbr>toooooooooooooooolooooooooooooooooooong/
</a>
```

But this doesn't work in windows nor in iOS (see https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-wbr/).

I tried to use `&shy;` which works fine, but produces a - when the line breaks.

Is there any other way which will work in most mail-clients?

Comment: Is there a need for the URL to be visible? You could just put some text within the anchor tags instead?

Comment: It's a kind of openness the owner of the company we are working for wants to show: "This is not a phising-mail." - altough this could be faked as well.

Comment: Then the rest of the design of the email should lend credence to that. Long links in an email can look suspicious themselves.

Comment: copy a shortening service such as https://tinyurl.com or similar to your own url redirector, so you present a short url (unque key) and that can redirect to the full url via your PHP

Comment: @Martin I guess that defeats the purpose of OP's customer. And I personally find it pretty suspicious if companies hide there URL behind a link-shortening service because you never know what kind of website you'll be redirected to. Atleast with bitly / tinyurl and stuff like that.

Answer (score 3):

I created a 600px wide `td` with a 40px padding, a 1px border and set a basic font style. I added a `p` tag to wrap the `href` and added the following inline style to both: `word-break: break-all; white-space: wrap;`.

I tested this with Litmus in Outlook, IOS, Gmail and it wraps without any difficulties.

```
<p style="word-break: break-all; white-space: wrap;">
  <a style="word-break: break-all; white-space: wrap;" href="http://stackoverflow.com">
https://stackoverflow.comThisisaverylongurlwithoutabreakoraspaceusingonlyforwardslashestobreakupwordswithcsslikeyouwouldfindinareallylongurl.html</a>
</p>
```

**Full table code**:

https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/9f3pcqnx/

[image: Outlook 2016 sample]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to wrap the display text into a div and then make use of the `text-overflow` css attribute.

```html
<a href="http://google.de">
   <div style="text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;max-width:200px">
     http://this-is-a-very-long-url-you-probably-never-want-to-see-but-hey-lets-pretend-we-want-this.xxx/why/on/earth/am/I/writing/so/much/text
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a normal URL there are lots of characters where breaks will occur such as the dash or slash (On Gmail, they will auto-add `<wbr>` before every slash / ), for some email clients.

iOS tends to set break-all automatically.

Yahoo doesn't seem to respond to anything other than `<wbr>` (or `&shy;`).

Thus, for a long WORD (could be different if there are other characters that would mean `break-word` is better), a cross-email solution for 2020 is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="200"><p style="overflow-wrap: break-all; word-wrap: break-all; word-break: break-all;">adsfasdfasdfasdfasdf<wbr>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfdasfasdfasdfasdfasdf<wbr>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You may be able to get away with `overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word` depending on what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Strange thing is, in Outlook the wordbreak is:
https://<wbr>www.example.com/<wbr>this/<wbr>is/<wbr>a/<wbr>very/<wbr>long/<wbr>link/<wbr>which/<wbr>might/<wbr>be/<wbr>toooooooooooooooolooooooooooooooooooong/

https://www.example.com/this/is/a/very/long/link/which/might/be/toooooooooooooooolo[[here is the break in Outlook]oooooooooooooooooong/